# How change axis limits in scatter matrix in plotly express?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following lines of code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df_fases,
    dimensions=["titanite", "amphibole", "epidote", "chlorite","garnet","ilmenite","rutile"], width=1000,
    height=1000, title="Rangos de umbral (vmax) por mineral")
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=4))

[enter image description here][1]

fig.show()
```

... but the x and y axes when I change them with `fig.update_xaxes (range = [1.5, 4.5])` and `fig.update_yaxes (range = [3, 9])`, it only changes some graphics of the scatter matrix plot.How change axis limits in scatter matrix in plotly express for all graphs?

[image: image scatter matrix]

Comment: What do you mean with  "some graphics of the scatter matrix plot"? could you upload a figure to show the behaviour?

Comment: Only the superior corner graphs changes, but the others graphs no.

Comment: I just added the resulting image

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 7 features so you will need to use `fig.update_layout` and loop through `xaxis1... xaxis7` as well as `yaxis1... yaxis7`. I have hardcoded the number of features for your particular problem, but you can modify this as needed.

```
fig.update_layout({"xaxis"+str(i+1): dict(range = [1.5, 4.5]) for i in range(7)})
fig.update_layout({"yaxis"+str(i+1): dict(range = [3, 9]) for i in range(7)})
```

Here is an example of the same thing on the iris data set, where I set the range of each plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
    dimensions=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"],
    color="species", symbol="species",
    title="Scatter matrix of iris data set",
    labels={col:col.replace('_', ' ') for col in df.columns}) # remove underscore

fig.update_layout({"xaxis"+str(i+1): dict(range = [0, 10]) for i in range(4)})
fig.update_layout({"yaxis"+str(i+1): dict(range = [0, 10]) for i in range(4)})
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]